# MS Word 2016 customize captions

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016

Default caption and cross-reference is working fine, but it almost impossible to customize.
For example - default is (depending on chapter):

```
Figure 1
```

or

```
Figure 2.1
```

I would like it something like:

```
1.1. Fig.
```

or

```
1. fig.
```

Is the any possibilities to make it with built-in functions? (I only can change word 'Figure', not the order of letters and numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution - instead of 'Figure ' just one space (MS Word does not accept empty value). And write down 'Fig.' by myself.